# PHP content read file location

Tags: 8

i added the module php to enable the insertion of [php](https://www.drupal.org/project/php) content 
now i want to add script that read from xml file.
My question is : where to add the xml file (the path on where to put my public files), i tried to add them under  `drupal\sites\default\files` but it doesn't work

Comment: Don't use the php module, ever, unless you want to potentially break your site and introduce security holes. If you want to add custom functionality to your site you should consider writing your own modules instead.

Answer (score -1):

It's under the Drupal folder himself.
I check it with `echo getcwd()`